# Nagios notification client for mac?

Tags: macos, nagios

I recently switched to a mac and am currently looking for a Nagios client that displays the Nagios notifications & alerts.
There are quite a few apps for the iPhone and iPad, but I haven't found anything for the Mac yet.

Under Windows I simply used the Nagios Notification Checker plugin for Firefox, but I would prefer a native app, which notifies via Growl or sits in the topbar and notifies any alerts.

Is there anything like that available for the mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an out of the box client, but the following web page describes how to integrate Nagios with Growl to let you know when there is an issue: http://gothamlabs.org/?p=90

Comment: The link above has been flagged as malicious, beware.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is nagstamon (http://nagstamon.ifw-dresden.de/). It's written in python and works on Mac fine. That said, it's not my favorite application design in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find something like this either, except for [NagiosDock](http://nagiosdock.sourceforge.net/) (which is old and runs only on PowerPC), so I wrote this:

https://github.com/bradleypeabody/MacNagios

Can monitor multiple instances, shows color coded status info in top status bar, and alerts using Notification Center.